# I don't recognize the symbol on top of this note. What is it, and how does it affect the note?

Tags: sheet-music, blues, trombone, articulation

This is a picture of the note and the symbol. It's part of a blues trombone solo. I would like to know what the symbol is and how I should play it.

[image]

Comment: The symbol indicates how the tone has to move.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

That is a bend or a dip.  You make a clear attack on the note and then do a very slight glissando around a quarter or half step down and then return to the original pitch.

Comment: Sorry -- I clicked on 'Answer; then made a cup of tea while I thought about it! I think we've described it identically so I'll upvote your answer.

Comment: I often need to notate such articulations in transcriptions. Would a similar, inverted mark be generally understood to mean a slight **raising** of the pitch before returning to center?

Comment: @JimL. In transcriptions you'd probably be fine. You'd generally be using those for academic purposes where the idea is to imitate the recording, not play it in the abstract without hearing it.  While I can't recall ever seeing that, if it was accompanied by the recording it woudl be obvious what you meant.  Its rare for me to play something like that but I have seen it before let me see if I can find the recording of that...

Answer (score 9):

It's a bend: an articulation mark representing a brief flattening of the note.The note is attacked in tune but is immediately flattened - by up to a semitone - before coming up to pitch again.